# Is the MIPS instruction not I type or R type instruction?

Tags: mips

When talking about sign-extended instructions I think of the I-instruction (beq, bne, addi, etc) if I am correct, but I am not sure if the MIPS instruction NOT is I type or R Type

Comment: There is technically no `NOT` instruction in MIPS. `NOT` is a synthetic instruction. Convert it to an actual MIPS instruction first.

Answer (score 0):

NOT is a pseudo instruction that inverts the given input. I believe the real instruction is a logical operation with  the zero register which is R type.